# Django "global login" middleware causing duplicate GET requests

Tags: python, django, middleware

I have a Django website that requires users to be logged in to view any page. I added some middleware according to the instructions on [this page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahMQ1XNLtAxsJ%3aonecreativeblog.com/post/59051248/django-login-required-middleware%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). The middleware does redirect users to the login page as expected, however the GET request is duplicated every time. Why is the request sent twice? (Or possibly output to the Django console twice?) Here is the output from the Django console after navigating to `127.0.0.1/reservations/`:

```
[08/May/2012 15:08:41] "GET /reservations/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/May/2012 15:08:42] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 575
[08/May/2012 15:08:42] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 575
```

Comment: I had a simular problem. Turned out it was one of my firefox extension doing that extra request.. Does this happend on two different browsers?

Comment: That's it! Chrome ends up requesting the login page twice, while IE & Firefox only do it once. That's so strange, I have no idea why that would happen. Were you able to solve the similar problem from a while back? (P.S. post your answer so I can mark it as correct :-).

Comment: Glad you found it.. My problem was related to a certificate checker extension (I think, if I remember). Guess it was half a year ago..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem and it was a firefox extension I used causing this weird issue.
Try with another browser to see if the problem goes away. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yslow extenstion on firefox caused this error on my devel system.